# jQuery button not showed as a jQuery button in a tabbed page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a button in a jQuery tabbed page declared like this:

```
<input id="buttonSave" type="submit" value="Save" />
```

I also have the script below:

```
$('#buttonSave').button();
$("#buttonSave").live('click', function () {
    alert('Button clicked');
});
```

When the button is clicked I have the message 'Button clicked'. That's ok. But the button has not the look'n feel of a jQuery button.

Any idea?

***To be clear, I add here some screenshots.***

Below you can see my page with the tabbed page at the bottom.

[image]

I trigger the script below in order to render my buttons as jQuery buttons:

```
$(":button").button();
```

This script update my page as showed below:

[image]

As you can see, only the button located on the main page is rendered as jQuery. Others buttons (located on the tabbed page) didn't render correctly.

Comment: Is the jQuery UI button widget source included in the page as well as the stylesheets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: Change your `live` function to `bind`. If you don't see a 'Button clicked' message, try to put your script after the  html code.

Comment: this doesn't work. I didn't see 'Button clicked' anymore and my button is not rendered as a jQuery button look'n feel. The problem is that my button is contained in a tabbed page and this tabbed page is rendered after the pahe has been generated. For the event on the click of the button we have the 'live' solution but I still have the problem of rendering the look of the jQuery button.

Comment: Maybe you are using ajax to load tabbed page content? If so, try to include the script with `$('#buttonSave').button();` to the ajax-call response.

Comment: I tried but it fails. The button is not rendered as a button. It is rendered as a simple text link.

Comment: Try to add `$('#buttonSave').button();` code to you click handler function (right after alert function call), to test if the button appearance will be changed when it's clicked. If appearance is not changed — most likely the problem is in css. Also be sure to check that you don't have other elements with 'buttonSave' id on the whole page.

Comment: If I cut & paste my button from my tabbed page to the parent page, my button is rendered correctly as a jQuery button! So the problem is around my tabbed page. Is it possible to have a jQuery button on a tabbed page?

Comment: If you attach an archive with generated html code of the main page and tabbed page, tab plugin script, css file — it will help to resolve the issue.

Comment: The problem was located in my CSS file. I restyle some 'a' (links) for the tab header to render a transparent background and it also changed the background of my buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you forgot to include css file for jQuery UI in your html page markup.

Comment: Oh, maybe as a workaround you will try to call button() method on activating the needed tab? like this: `$( ".selector" ).tabs({
   select: function(event, ui) { ... }
});`

Comment: Ok, I've checked by myself. Result is here: [jQuery UI tabs and buttons within](http://bo.lt/3joyr) . No bugs, all works just as expected. Check your code, maybe you misspelled somewhere... And I used the `$(":button").button();` function, perhaps this will help

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you that you also included the jqueryUI library and the relevant css file?

Otherwise your button won't be styled.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="YOUR-PATH_HERE/jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8" />
```

Comment: Peluchetti: yes, the jQuery UI library is included. I'm pretty sure the problem is about this tabbed jQuery page...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have linked JQuery CSS files properly. Example:

```
<head>
 ...
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="script/jquery-ui.css"/>
 ...
</head>
```

Good Luck :)

Comment: Bhat: other jQuery buttons rendered very wel and are not inserted in a tabbed jQuery page. So I think the problem is specific to my tabbed page but I dont know what.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ensure all your dom elements were rendered before you tried to convert them to the jquery UI style?

```
// Document ready
$(function()
{
    $(":button").button();
}
```